# button in .html doesn't work in jquery

Tags: jquery, alert

I add two buttons in a page . when I clicked on first button, Content (containing of another button) will be shown to user . problem is here : the second button is into this content that doesn't work. alert hasn't been shown to user .

```
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/k5bL7pkj/5/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach event handlers to something that exists on the page, then filter the events down to elements that may exist later.

Example:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#ss', function () {
    alert("TEST");
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5bL7pkj/7/)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the element is created at runtime, you must add the event after creating the element.

**Try this code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#aa").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' /><button id='ss'>SSSSS</button>");

        $('#ss').click(function () {
           alert("TEST");
        });

    });

});
```

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/k5bL7pkj/8/

Answer (score 0):

always use all your "click, change or keyup" functions on document, it will help you in future...

```
$(document).on('click','#aa', function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' /><button id='ss'>SSSSS</button>");
});

$(document).on('click','#ss', function () {
    alert("TEST");
});
```